# How to get all HMSET - Laravel Redis

Tags: laravel, redis

[Hmset Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8OgK.png)

This is my demo hmset example, I try to get all hmset list by Redis::hgetall("hmset_demo:user_id:*"), but it return a empty array [].

How can I get this return:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name edited 1",
    "description": "desc edited 1",
    "avatar": "xxx 1"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name edited 1",
    "description": "desc edited 1",
    "avatar": "xxx 1"
},
...
]
```

PS: I use the following code to insert:

```
Redis::hmset("hmset_demo:user_id:".$id, [
            'id'    =>  $id,
            'name'    =>  'name edited '.$id,
            'description'    =>  'desc edited'.$id,
            'avatar'    =>  'xxx'.$id,
        ]);
```

I can get specific hmset data by this code:

```
$id = 1;
Redis::hgetall("hmset_demo:user_id:".$id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards in key names.

Let's see an example. We store two hash type keys

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET hmset_demo:user_id:0 NAME PETER
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET hmset_demo:user_id:1 NAME GWEN
```

We can retrieve their value by its key

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL hmset_demo:user_id:0
1) "NAME"
2) "PETER"

127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL hmset_demo:user_id:1
1) "NAME"
2) "GWEN"
```

But we cannot use wildcards with HGETALL command

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL hmset_demo:user_id:*
(empty array)
```

If you need to use wildcards to retrieve a lot of keys, you can use [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan/) COMMAND

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0 MATCH hmset_demo:user_id:* COUNT 10
1) "0"
2) 1) "hmset_demo:user_id:1"
   2) "hmset_demo:user_id:0"
```

Iterate each element from the resulset and retrieve its values using HGETALL

There is no way to retrieve everything using just one Redis command

Also, [HMSET](https://redis.io/commands/hmset/) command is deprecated. You should use [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset/) instead.